# how to call Sortable Event when sorting between the same list Jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have two list that are sortable . when i am sorting an item from list1 to list2 the function works but when i am sorting in the same list the event didnt work.

i was using the Recieve Event and i change it to update but didnt work too.

is there any function thats activated when i am changing positions of items in the same list ???

how i can get an event when i am sorting in same list ( change the position of items in same list ) ??

```
  update : function(e, ui) { 
                 //alert('zone : ');
                           }
```

Comment: i found that the function deactivate but i cant get now the sender or the reciever id of the list i was find them like that :                   valuesender = ui.sender.attr('id');
valuereciever = $(this).attr('id'); but with deactivate i am getting the same value of the reciever.

Comment: Please post a complete code example and if possible, an example at jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `update` event of the *sortable*, which, as described in the [JQuery UI API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), contains a `null` value for the `sender` attribute when the sorting occurs in the same list.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update : function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.sender == null && ui.item.parent().is($(this))) {
            // Items were sorted within the same list
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing, if you move an item out of A into B, an "update" event is triggered on B with sender = null

Answer (score 0):

deactivate: function (event, ui) { yourFunction(event, ui, this); }